# pygame.draw.rect not working properly, only drawing part of a sprite group

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to create a rain grid in five rows for a couple of days now but `pygame.draw.rect` is only drawing the first row.
I have added print statements to try to find out if the rect positions were wrong but apparently they are correct. While I'm sure I'm doing something stupid in the code I cant work out what it is..
Could somebody try to help me?

This is the code I user to create the Rain Grid:

```
def _create_rain_grid(self):
        """Create the rain grid"""
        # Create a rain drop and find the number of rain drop in a row
        # Spacing between each rain drop is equal to 5* its width
        rain_drop = Rain(self)
        rain_drop_width, rain_drop_height = rain_drop.rect.size
        available_space_x = self.settings.screen_width
        number_rain_drops_x = available_space_x // (5 * rain_drop_width)
        
        # Create the rain grid in 5 rows
        rows = 5
        for row_number in range(rows):
            for rain_drop_number in range(number_rain_drops_x):
                print(f"Row Number: {row_number} - Rain numb: {rain_drop_number}")
                self._create_rain(rain_drop_number, row_number)

    def _create_rain(self, rain_number, row_number):
        """Create a rain drop and place it in the row"""
        rain_drop = Rain(self)
        rain_drop_width, rain_drop_height = rain_drop.rect.size
        rain_drop.x = rain_drop_width + 5 * rain_drop_width * rain_number
        rain_drop.rect.x = rain_drop.x
        rain_drop.rect.y = rain_drop_height + 3 * rain_drop_height * row_number
        print(f"x: {rain_drop.rect.x} | y: {rain_drop.rect.y}")
        self.rain.add(rain_drop)
```

And to show it in the screen:

```
    def _update_screen(self):
        """Updates images on the screen, and flip to the new screen."""
        self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)
        self.ship.blitme()
        for bullet in self.bullets.sprites():
            bullet.draw_bullet()
        self.aliens.draw(self.screen)
        for rain_drop in self.rain.sprites():
            rain_drop.draw_rain()

        pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] in your question and don't just link to external resources.

Comment: You need to add the code to the question. A link to an off-site resource is not sufficient. Links to external resources tend to break and the resource may no longer be available in the future. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thanks, I will add the code to the question and remove the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:
When the rain drop is updated, `self.rect.y` is set by `self.y`:

> ```py
> class Rain(Sprite):
>    # [...]
>
>    def update(self):
>        """Move the rain down"""
>        self.y += (self.settings.rain_speed)
>        self.rect.y = self.y
> ```

This doesn't work, because the `y` attribute is not initialized. You have to set `rain_drop.y` like you do with `rain_drop.y`:

```py
def _create_rain(self, rain_number, row_number):
        """Create a rain drop and place it in the row"""
        rain_drop = Rain(self)
        rain_drop_width, rain_drop_height = rain_drop.rect.size

        rain_drop.x = rain_drop_width + 5 * rain_drop_width * rain_number
        rain_drop.y = rain_drop_height + 3 * rain_drop_height * row_number

        rain_drop.rect.x = rain_drop.x
        rain_drop.rect.y = rain_drop.y
       
        print(f"x: {rain_drop.rect.x} | y: {rain_drop.rect.y}")
        self.rain.add(rain_drop)
```

---

---

You need 2 nested loops to draw a grid.

```py
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(5):
        rect = (i*tile_size, j*tile_size, tile_size, tile_size)
```

---

Minimal example:

[image]

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 300))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False          

    window.fill(0)

    tile_size = 50
    for i in range(5):
        for j in range(5):
            rect = (25 + i*tile_size, 25 + j*tile_size, tile_size, tile_size)
            pygame.draw.rect(window, (255, 255, 255), rect, 2)
   
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

Comment: @lucasfonseca I've extended the answer (at the beginning).

Comment: You are just awesome! :D It worked! Thanks! Apparently I don't have enough reputation to update your answer XD